# C++ for each in on custom collections

Tags: c++, collections, foreach, loops

So since it was introduced I have been loving the `for each` in keywords to iterate `STL collections`.(I'm a very very big fan of syntactic sugar).

My question is how can I write a custom collection that can be iterated using these keywords?

Essentially, what APi do I need to expose for my collections to be iterable using these keywords?

I apologize if this sounds blunt, but please do not respond with "use boost", "don't write your own collections", or the like. Pursuit of knowledge, my friends. If it's not possible, hey, I can handle that.

I'd also very much so prefer not to have to inject an STL iterator into my collections.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you talking about the `std::for_each` algorithm? Or the range-based for-loop introduced in C++11?

Comment: @jalf: I'm referring to the Microsoft 'for each in' context sensitive keywords. Although the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms177202.aspx) only details C++/CLI, this works in native.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a good explanation of iterable data structures ([Range-Based loops](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html)):

In order to make a data structure iterable, it must work similarly to the existing STL iterators.

1. There must be `begin` and `end` methods that operate on that structure,
   either as members or as stand-alone functions, and that return iterators to
   the beginning and end of the structure.
2. The iterator itself must support an `operator*` method, an `operator !=` method, and an `operator++` method, either as members or as stand-alone functions.

Note, in `C++11` there is an integrated support for range-based loops without the use of `STL`, though the above conditions hold for this as well. You can read about it at the same link above.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. This is exactly the kind of information I needed.

Comment: Can you add some links that confirm/explain this statement "Note, in C++11 there is an integrated support for range-based loops without the use of STL"?

Comment: @NicoBerrogorry Google is your friend. Type "C++11 range-based loop"

Comment: Actually, I did it immediately after posting my comment and I found the material I needed. Anyways, everything I needed was already explained in your first link, It seems I've read your answer in a hurry...

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear from your quesiton whether you're talking about `std::for_each` defined in the `<algorithm>` header, or the range-based for loop introduced in C++11.

However, the answer is similar for both.

Both operate on iterators, rather than the collection itself.

So you need to

1. define an iterator type which satisfies the requirements placed on it by the STL (the C++ standard, really). (The main things are that it must define `operator++` and `operator*`, and a couple of other operations and typedefs)
2. for `std::for_each`, there is no 2. You're done. You simply pass two such iterators to `std::for_each`. For the range-based for loop, you need to expose a pair of these iterators via the `begin()` and `end()`  functions.

And... that's it.

The only tricky part is really creating an iterator which complies with the requirements. Boost (even though you said you didn't want to use it) has a library which aids in implementing custom iterators (Boost.Iterator). There is also the `std::iterator` class which is intended as a base class for custom iterator implementations. But neither of these are *necessary*. Both are just convenience tools to make it easier to create your own iterator.

Comment: std::iterator is deprecated in C++17